# Asp.Net MVC Filtering DropDownList ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm learning Asp.Net MVC. I had a small problem when dealing with dropdownlist.

I don't want to list users which have Admin role

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleId != "1"));
        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(user, "Id", "UserName");
        return View();
    }
```

I get this errors

> Error 2   Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
>
> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'bool'

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should filter your query to get only non-admin users:

```
var user = db.Users.Where(user => user.Role.Name != "Admin").ToList();
```

You must create a `List<SelectListItem>` in controller like this:

```
dropdownItems.AddRange(new[]
{
     new SelectListItem() {Text = "User1", Value = "1", Selected = true },
     new SelectListItem() {Text = "User2", Value = "2", Selected = false },
     new SelectListItem() {Text = "User3", Value = "3", Selected = false }
});

ViewBag.DropDownItems = dropdownItems;
```

And in razor view you must create `<select>` tag like this:

```
<select name="Users" id="Users">
      @foreach (var selectListItem in ViewBag.DropDownItems as List<SelectListItem>)
      {
          <option value="@selectListItem.Value" selected="@selectListItem.Selected">@selectListItem.Text</option>
      }
</select>
```

Comment: i think you misundersttod question, question is  not this

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question

Answer (score 0):

You can directly load all the non-admin users and avoid filtering the data in your code.

```
public ActionResult Create() {
   // Get the Id for the "Admin" role
   int AdminRoleID = db.Roles.First(r => r.Name == "Admin").Id;

   // Get the users that don't have the role "Admin"
   var user = db.Users.Where(u => db.UserRoles.Where(r => r.roleId != AdminRoleID).Select(r => r.UserId).Contains(u.Id));

   ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(user, "Id", "UserName");
   return View();
}
```

**Note**: Assuming that the `UserRoles` table is accessed by the `db.UserRoles` DbSet.

Comment: I couldn't understand the part Select(r => r.Id).Contains(u.Id), r.Id is role id and u.Id is user id

Comment: You are correct, that was a typing error of mine, I updated my answer

Comment: Well the problem is r doesnt contains UserId, we might reach it through r.Users.Where(p=>p.UserId) but i get errors if i do it that way.

Comment: Can you give us then the fields of the tables `Users` and `Roles`?

Comment: it's the asp.net identity tables Users contains userid, roles contains rolename and roleid, userroles contains userid and roleid.

Comment: I updated my answer again, I hope now this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign the db to *"user"* in your selectlist.

Like this:

```
 ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleId != "1")), "Id", "UserName");
```

Hope it works.